# How reliable is LocationManager's getLastKnownLocation and how often is it updated?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am building an app that can use a user's current location on certain actions.  Location is more of a benefit to the user rather than a critical part of the process.  I'm only interested in very rough accuracy and it can be off by 5 or even 10 miles and still be of value.  General plan was to see if the network provider was enabled and then just do

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

Assuming that no other apps are running, will the phone automatically periodically update the network location?  I.e. there will likely always be a value returned by this code which will meet my needs?

EDIT:

I've been doing a bit more research and I think the question I was really trying to ask here was if the Android operating system or the phone itself would update the last known location for the network provider as the phone locked onto different cell phone towers or wifi networks.  The answer appears to be no.  After force stopping all apps on my phone which I know to interaction with location services, the last known location has stopped updating.  So, I'm guessing that these days chances are that most phones will have some location services running in the background updating the last known location but the phone itself won't do it.  Hence I think I'll be going with some form of requesting location updates if the last known location is too old.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

getLastKnownLocation() only returns the last fix.  So if no location providers are being updated the return value of getLastKnownLocation() will not change.  The location object will also provide you with accuracy and time of the fix.

I would look at this post for more information.  You could use some version of the one shot location.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: Be aware that the source code in that link contains bugs. LegacyLastLocationFinder.java: 1) else-if on line 95 should update `bestAccuracy`. 2) line 108: `bestTime > minTime` should be `bestTime < minTime`

Comment: link is dead as of 5/15/2022

Answer (score 4):

Frohnzie is correct about getLastKnownLocation. Getting location is an expensive operation, so it only happens when an app requests it. I've often driven 30 miles or so, opened the foursquare app on my phone, and it showed me venus that were 30 miles away. Clearly they were using getLastKnownLocation.

For your use case, I would recommend [LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29). You can specify an accuracy and a timeout. So if the phone can't quickly find a rough estimate of the user's location, you can just forego location since it is not crucial to your application.

Comment: Interesting.  My Network provider seems to update every minute or so.  Is your 4square app using GPS to update (though I suppose its impossible to know which provider they are using for the lastKnownLocation)?  I'm trying to peg down how often network provider updates happen on phones (without being initiated by an app)

Comment: I found that if I used requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this) I would get an update about every 45sec.