# getLastKnownLocation sometimes returns null

Tags: android, location, android-gps

Let me start by acknowledging that there are many results when you search for this particular question. Yet, nothing I've tried, according to those answers, works. Sometimes I get the location, sometimes I don't. If I play with the `Location` enabling/disabling I always get `null` when calling `getLastKnownLocation`. If I sometimes manually revoke the `Location` permission and enable it again, it works. I've tried changing the `LocationManager` to `location = locationManager  .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);` but it doesn't work.

Basically, I am doing the following:

```
    public class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

    public static final int LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE = 109;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60;

    private static boolean isGpsStatusChanged = false;
    private static AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private boolean canGetLocation = false;
    private Location location;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private NewLocationListener newLocationListener;

    public interface NewLocationListener {
        void onLocationChanges(Location location);
    }

    public GPSTracker() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) BaseApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPSTracker", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Log.d("GPSTracker", "Network - location manager != null");
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.d("GPSTracker", "Network - last known location != null");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            newLocationListener.onLocationChanges(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPSTracker", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            Log.d("LastKnownLocation", "Location: " + locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                newLocationListener.onLocationChanges(location);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return location;
    }

    public static boolean isGpsEnabled() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) BaseApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context
                .LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void setNewLocationListener(NewLocationListener newLocationListener) {
        this.newLocationListener = newLocationListener;
    }

    public void removeLocationListener() {
        this.newLocationListener = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("InlinedApi")
    public void showSettingsAlert(final Context context) {
        if (alertDialog != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        }
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.gps_window_title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.gps_window_message);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.gps_window_button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.gps_window_button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                alertDialog = null;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (newLocationListener != null) {
            newLocationListener.onLocationChanges(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public static boolean isGpsStatusChanged() {
        return isGpsStatusChanged;
    }

    public static void setIsGpsStatusChanged(boolean isGpsStatusChanged) {
        GPSTracker.isGpsStatusChanged = isGpsStatusChanged;
    }
}
```

And then in my `fragment`:

```
private void statGPSLocationTracking() {

    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "start gps update");
    // check if GPS enabled
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker();
    gpsTracker.setNewLocationListener(newLocationListener);
    gpsTracker.getLocation();

    if (!gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "GPS not enabled, show enable dialog");
        // stop the gps tracker(removes the location update listeners)
        gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();

        // ask user to enable location
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert(getActivity());
    }
}

private GPSTracker.NewLocationListener newLocationListener = new GPSTracker.NewLocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanges(Location loc) {
        if (getActivity() == null) {
            return;
        }
        // GPS location determined, load the web page and pass the coordinates in the header location section
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Location listener onLocationChanges: " + loc);
        infoManager.setCurrentLocation(loc);
        checkRadioInfoNeeded();

        // stop the gps tracker(removes the location update listeners)
        gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How reliable is LocationManager's getLastKnownLocation and how often is it updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423624/how-reliable-is-locationmanagers-getlastknownlocation-and-how-often-is-it-updat)

Answer (score 0):

Without this location permission `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` the `getLastKnownLocation()` will always return null.

`getLastKnownLocation()` does not return location immediately, it takes some time.

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60;
```

this to

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 5 * 1000;
```

Also remove your code which gets location from network. Go to Google maps and see if maps is able to detect your current location. If your map is able to get location then your code too should get location place breakpoints and see where the real issue is.